# JS Empty focused Input

Tags: javascript

If the user enters an invalid number, I want to empty the input. Negative numbers and numbers that are decimal are not allowed.

This is my Js Function:

```
function calcPrice() {
    var count = $('#placeCount').val();

    if(count%1 == 0 && count > 0) {
        if(count == 0) {
            var output = "";
        } else if(count == 1) {
            var output = "€ 2,49";
        } else if(count > 1 && count != 0) {
            var output = ("€ " + (2*count-0.01));
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#placeCount').html("");
    }
    $('#priceOutput').html(output);
}
```

But somehow the input is not empty if I enter a count that goes into the else section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the value of the input with `val()` instead of `html()`:

```
function calcPrice() {
    var count = $('#placeCount').val();

    if(count%1 == 0 && count > 0) {
        if(count == 0) {
            var output = "";
        } else if(count == 1) {
            var output = "€ 2,49";
        } else if(count > 1 && count != 0) {
            var output = ("€ " + (2*count-0.01));
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#placeCount').val("");
    }
    $('#priceOutput').html(output);
}
```